# How can I load local images asynchronously?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to load a local image asynchronously, but "sprite.create" takes so much time which make my UI stop. How can I fix this?

```
WWW www = new WWW (filePath);
    yield return www;

    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.ARGB32, true);
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
    www.Dispose ();
    www = null;

    curTexture = texture;
    img.sprite = Sprite.Create (curTexture, new Rect (0, 0, curTexture.width, curTexture.height), new Vector2 (0.5f, 0.5f));
```

**Update 2016.08.26:**

I used RawImage to set texture instead of using Image which need to change texture to sprite.

Another question is that www.LoadImageIntoTexture is also take so much time. I used www.texture before, but I found it failed to load some png from android device which just display a blue image.

Comment: please show how you are calling the function this code is inside.

Comment: Also, have you considered trying getting rid of the `Texture2D texture = ...` line and just do `curTexture = www.texture;`?

Comment: you could use UI.RawImage instead of UI.Image and directly assign the [WWW.texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html) to [RawImage.texture](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage-texture.html)

Comment: @JeanLuc RawImage is good for me. With RawImage, I don't need to change texture to sprite anymore. Thx !!

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I can not load any png image from my android phone with www.texture which just display blue color.

Comment: I posted the RawImage solution as an answer. The blue color issue fails with what kind of error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment I would recommend using [RawImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-RawImage.html), which has a [texture property](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage-texture.html), so you don't need to create a Sprite.

```
[SerializeField] private RawImage _rawImage;

public void DownloadImage(string url)
{
    StartCoroutine(DownloadImageCoroutine(url));
}

private IEnumerator DownloadImageCoroutine(string url)
{
    using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
    {
        // download image
        yield return www;

        // if no error happened
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            // get texture from WWW
            Texture2D texture = www.texture;

            yield return null; // wait a frame to avoid hang

            // show image
            if (texture != null && texture.width > 8 && texture.height > 8)
            {
                _rawImage.texture = texture;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call a coroutine using this:

```
StartCoroutine(eImageLoad(filepath));
```

And here is the definition:

```
IEnumerator eImageLoad(string path)
{
    WWW www = new WWW (path);

    //As @ Scott Chamberlain suggested in comments down below
    yield return www;

    //This is longer but more explanatory
    //while (false == www.isDone)
    //{
    //    yield return null;
    //}

    //As @ Scott Chamberlain suggested in comments you can get the texture directly

    curTexture = www.Texture;

    www.Dispose ();
    www = null;

    img.sprite = Sprite.Create (curTexture, new Rect (0, 0, curTexture.width, curTe
}
```

Comment: Why the while loop? just do `yield return www;`, the `WWW` class [supports returning it for a yield](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html).

Comment: Yes, you can do that but I edited it to make it more understandable.

Comment: Ok, I see the comment now (i did miss it before), but you still have not explained why you changed it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain OP can actually use the `while (!www.isDone){}` especially  when he wants to see the status of the download. Since OP is having problems, using the `while` loop Cabrra had and putting  `www.progress` inside it would help OP troubleshoot his problem. This  can't be done with `yield return www` so there is nothing wrong with the first code Cabrra had.

Comment: I use "StartCoroutine" too. But the methor "Sprite.Create" take so much time after "yield return www".